# mzR / Rcpp package anomaly

Tags: r

I'm having the following error when I try to load the mzR libary. Does someone have a clue where to search for a solution. I tried to re-install *mzR* and *Rcpp* also, but with no effect.

```
> library(mzR)
Lade nötiges Paket: Rcpp
Error : .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'mzR' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
  Aufruf: value[[3L]](cond)
  Fehler: failed to load module Ramp from package mzR
kann Vektor der Größe 13.2 GB nicht allozieren
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
1: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
   mzR has been built against a different Rcpp version
 than is installed on your system. This might lead to errors
 when loading mzR. If you encounter such issues, please send
 a report, including the output of sessionInfo() to the Bioc
 mailing list -- http://www.bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list.
2: In Module(m, pkg, mustStart = TRUE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8183Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In Module(m, pkg, mustStart = TRUE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8183Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In Module(m, pkg, mustStart = TRUE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8183Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In Module(m, pkg, mustStart = TRUE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8183Mb: see help(memory.size)
Fehler: Laden von Paket oder Namensraum für ‘mzR’ fehlgeschlagen
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.11.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Biobase_2.20.1     BiocGenerics_0.6.0 parallel_3.0.3
```

**mzR** version is 1.6.3 does the problem have a general solution? I don't want to run into the same problem in every version ...

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Either reinstall both from *source* or install the version of Rcpp against which `mzR` was built.

Comment: How can I find out which version of Rcpp was that? I checked that mzr requirement is >=0.10.x but this does not help me sadly.

Comment: I can read that right in your question. `mzR has been built against a different Rcpp version
 than is installed on your system. This might lead to errors
 when loading mzR. If you encounter such issues, please send
 a report, including the output of sessionInfo() to the Bioc
 mailing list -- http://www.bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list.`

Comment: Are you suggesting to write to the package developer? I did that, but I think here there is something else the problem. Maybe the package versions differ, and can't get the right version running. Another problem could be that they compiled wrong, but I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple reinstall of *mzR* package I found this solution:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") 
biocLite("BiocUpgrade")
```

For me it seems that *bioconductor* was building the mzR package in a wrong way.

Comment: No need to worry, mate. Bioconductor was not wrong, your were
just a bit confused. Let's thank Bioconductor for doing such a
great job.