# Rcpp and mzR packages are not compatible R 3.1.0

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to install two packages (ProbMetab and metaXCMS) that are not available for R 3.2.0.

I've installed R 3.1.3, but now I can't get Rcpp and mzR working.

The initial error stated that my version of mzR was built against an older version of Rcpp (i.e. I had 0.11.6 and it was built against 0.11.3)

I've removed all traces of Rcpp and mzR, and installed 0.11.3 (and then 0.11.4 and 0.11.5) Edit: mzR was initially installed from bioconductor
    [`source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("mzR")`]
   as mentioned below. Now when mzR tries to load, Rstudio crashes.

I did find a similar problem here - 
[mzR / Rcpp package anomaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809741/mzr-rcpp-package-anomaly). The recommendation was to install the source packages for Rcpp and mzR. So I tried that next.

I got an immediate error with installation of mzR, stating I need ProtGenetics and zlibbioc. After installing ProtGenerics (again, source package here) and zlibbioc, I got a huge string of errors trying to install mzR.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocInstaller_1.16.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.3
```

Error following install of mzR:

```
    > install.packages("~/Downloads/mzR_2.2.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package ‘mzR’ ...
** libs
rm -f cramp.o ramp_base64.o ramp.o RcppRamp.o RcppRampModule.o rnetCDF.o
```

....

....

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mzR’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/mzR’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/Harris/Downloads/mzR_2.2.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: mzR is a Bioconductor package so usually the recommended installation is `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("mzR")`. This will install the version of mzR appropriate for your version of R; for R 3.1.3 this is Bioc version [3.0](http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.0), mzR 2.0.0.

Comment: I am not sure why it would Rcpp's fault if _I am trying to install two packages (ProbMetab and metaXCMS) that are not available for R 3.2.0._.  In any event, installation from source should work, as it did in the past. Start from the inside out, installing the _dependend-upon_ package first. Probably R (maybe 3.1.3), then Rcpp (the version valid at the time R 3.1.3 was current if the the newest will not work) and so on.